# Why my react native navigation bar's text not on the vertical center?

Tags: react-native

I use the Navigator.NavigationBar component to make a navbar, but the text not vertical centering.

Like this:

[image]

How can I solve this?

Comment: If my answer helps @Theodore, don't forget to mark it as the solution! :-) http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 3):

I just ran into this issue too. The solution:

```
<Navigator.NavigationBar
    routeMapper={{
        Title: (route, navigator, index, navState) =>
            {
                return (
                    <View style={{
                            justifyContent: 'center',
                            flex: 1
                        }}>
                        <Text style={{color: 'white'}}>Candidates</Text>
                    </View>
                );
            },
    }}
/>
```

So basically make sure there's a parent wrap on your navbar elements filling the navbars height (the `flex: 1` rule) and vertically center its contents with `justifyContent: 'center'`.

I've done the styles inline for this example, but of course it'd be more efficient to get those from a `StyleSheet` object.